# Is there a way to complete the Game Expert achievement in Game Dev Story?

Tags: achievements, game-dev-story

It seems to be bugged because there are two types of games that don't show up in the game. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: which types? did you check here:
http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Game_Dev_Story/Walkthrough

Comment: My achievement is 97% complete. I'm not sure which types are missing but I already have all the ones that you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe some achievements require starting a new game to complete.
http://www.gamespot.com/game-dev-story/forum/achievements-not-unlocking-58817903/

While this may not be true, I suggest making a new save file and see if that works.